# USA Southern Border Vehicular and Pedestrian Obstacles

Tags: geospatial

Is there a GIS source that contains the location and type of obstacles along the USA Southern border?  Additional meta data would be great as well; when it was install, dimensions, materials, number of repairs, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

[Homeland Infrastructure Foundation-Level Data (HIFLD)](https://gii.dhs.gov/hifld/) has an [Open Data Portal](https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/) where most of this data can be found.
[HIFLD 2018 Data Catalog (`.xlsx`)](https://gii.dhs.gov/hifld/sites/default/files/2018-11/HIFLD%202018%20Data%20Catalog.xlsx) lists all of their open data wares for the year.

Specifically, [borders](https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?group_ids=145978a632f44d62bc36a58092baa7d7), [boundaries](https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?group_ids=e5cf7f3805274fef90100ab704ee2ac1), [natural hazards](https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?group_ids=97516bd79a0d452192f792e0c8d5157f), and [transportation ground](https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?group_ids=dc2b19b1aad645c294f38cef40086ef4) datasets seem pertinent here.

Note: if the portal isn't definitive enough, go through the data catalog; searching for "border" returned six results, whereas searching the portal for the borders tag only yields three.

Answer (score 1):

all I know is they might have what you are looking for...

https://www.ibwc.gov/home.html

They have their geospatial data there.